# Deploying EJB3 in JBoss 4.0.5

Tags: java, deployment, jboss-4.0.x

For the past couple of days, I am trying to deploy EJB3 EAR in Jboss 4.0.5. It keeps giving me one error after another. Are there any tutorials that point deploying EJB 3 applications in Jboss 4.0.5 version. I googled it, but I don't find anything useful.

Comment: I think you should post your exceptions here and present a deployment architecture, where EJB3 reside, what are the deployment descriptors and so forth. In general, jboss 4.0.5 should support EJB3 that adheres JEE5 specification, and if I remember correctly it should work only with Java 5 (java 6 is not supported).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to setup your jboss server for ejb3 support using jems-installer. Please check this link https://developer.jboss.org/message/203479